# Including classpath resource in external log4j configuration

Tags: log4j2, xinclude

I use external log4j configuration and load it in servlet context listener using org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator

I would like to reference some application properties (like application version) that are generated on build time. 
Here is what I would like to do:

> /external-folder/log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" 
    monitorInterval="60">

    <xi:include href="log4j2-properties.xml" />

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %5p %t [${app-version}] %m (%F:%L) %n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
<!-- ... -->
</Configuration>
```

> log4j2-properties.xml

is supposed to be a classpath resource, *@version@* is filtered by gradle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Properties>
    <Property name="app-version">@version@</Property>
</Properties>
```

However this approach doesn't work. I can xinclude only resource from the same folder as top level log4j.xml

How can I solve my problem?

(I know how to do this using logback, but I would like to upgrade to log4j2)

Comment: If your log4j2.xml is an external file not on the classpath then I don't see why your properties would need to be on the classpath. The important thing is that XInclude be able to locate your log4j2-properties.xml so you need to be sure that the URL you're using is correct since that is how XInclude will locate the file. You're using a URL that is relative to the config file, which doesn't seem correct based on the info you provided.

Comment: As I have mentioned, I would like to have version information in the properties file. This is generated automatically during the build and will be part of generated EAR. However I would like to have master log4j config separately.